# Facebook Scraping returns error 500

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I'm using `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug` to determine what facebook sees from my page.

When I'm doing for my page, a Facebook scrape is returning a 500 error only because of this line

```
$photoObj=$facebook->api("/$photoId?access_token=$access_token");
```

although the page is executing correctly??

Any idea??

Comment: That error is in your own code - do all those variables have values? bear in mind the scraper operates in a logged-out context

Comment: I've noticed one more thing with the scrapper, it doesn't sees image URL like this --> http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/556898_400257580012798_100000856787624_1059515_311974781_n.jpg

Comment: Yeah, you have to host your own images, not use Facebook's CDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the technique of retrieving the image, now I do it like this:

```
$access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
$photoObj=file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$photoId?access_token=$access_token");
$photoObj=json_decode($photoObj);
$picURL=$photoObj->source;
```

and it works :-)